# how to link static jemalloc for mysql5.5

Tags: mysql

I want to link static jemalloc library for oracle mysql5.5 .If mysql5.1 ,i can do it :

```
LDFLAGS=” -lrt -ljemalloc -lstdc++ ” 
./configure –prefix=/usr/soft/install/mysql  \
–with-mysqld-user=mysql \
–with-plugins=partition,blackhole,csv,heap,innobase,myisam,myisammrg \
–with-charset=utf8 \
–with-collation=utf8_general_ci \
–with-extra-charsets=gbk,gb2312,utf8,ascii \
–with-big-tables \
–with-fast-mutexes \
–with-zlib-dir=bundled \
–enable-assembler \
–enable-profiling \
–enable-local-infile \
–enable-thread-safe-client \
–with-readline \
–with-pthread \
–with-embedded-server \
–with-mysqld-ldflags=-all-static \
–without-query-cache \
–without-geometry \
–without-debug \
–without-ndb-debug
make && make install
```

But i can not find a cmake's option with it in mysql5.5.
What can i do?